# How are batch statistics computed in Recurrent Batch Normalization?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, batch-normalization

I'm implementing recurrent BN per [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09025) in Keras, but looking at it and those citing it, a detail remains unclear to me: how are *batch statistics* computed? Authors omit explicit clarification, but state (pg. 3) (emphasis mine):

> At training time, the statistics E[**h**] and Var[**h**] are estimated by the sample mean and sample variance of the **current minibatch**

Yet [another paper](https://jaywhang.com/assets/batchnorm_rnn.pdf) (pg. 3) using and citing it describes:

> We subscript BN by time (BN_t) to indicate that each time step tracks its own mean and variance. In practice, we **track** these statistics as they change **over the course of training** using an *exponential moving average* (EMA)

My question's thus two-fold:

1. Are minibatch statistics computed *per immediate minibatch*, or as an *EMA*?
2. How are the inference parameters, shared across all timesteps, `gamma` and `beta` computed? Is the computation in (1) simply averaged across all timesteps? (e.g. average `EMA_t` for all `t`)

---

**Existing implementations**: in Keras and TF below, but are all outdated, and am unsure regarding correctness

- [Keras](https://github.com/udibr/keras/blob/lstmbn/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L863), [TF-A](https://github.com/tam17aki/recurrent-batchnorm-tensorflow/blob/master/BN_LSTMCell.py), and [TF-B](https://github.com/OlavHN/bnlstm/blob/master/lstm.py)
- All above agree that during training, *immediate minibatch* statistics are used, and that `beta` and `gamma` are updated as an EMA of these minibatches
- Problem: the `bn` operation (in A, and presumably B & C) is applied on a *single timestep* slice, to be passed to the `K.rnn` control flow for re-iteration. Hence, EMA is computed w.r.t. minibatches *and* timesteps - which I find questionable:

  - EMA is used in place of a simple average when population statistics are *dynamic* (e.g. minibatch-to-minibatch), whereas we have access to *all timesteps* in a minibatch prior having to update `gamma` and `beta`
  - EMA is a worse but at times necessary alternative to a simple average, but per above, we *can* use latter - so why don't we? Timestep statistics can be cached, averaged at the end, then discarded - holds also for `stateful=True`